# what is to be done to send a mail from curl from windows task scheduler or just by clicking on the batch file?

Tags: gmail, curl, smtp

when I run the following command in a script (using a win10 laptop)

```
c:\curl\bin\curl.exe -v -k --connect-timeout 100 --max-time 200 --url "smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465" --user "user@gmail.com:password" --mail-from "user@gmail.com" --mail-rcpt "user@yahoo.com" -H "To: user@yahoo.com"  --upload-file  C:\backup\securities02012024.log 2>c:\backup\curltest.log
```

1. when sent by clicking the batch file from file explorer or when run using task scheduler, it does not work
   Following is the error message

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Host smtp.gmail.com:465 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 172.253.118.109
*   Trying 172.253.118.109:465...
* connect to 172.253.118.109 port 465 from 0.0.0.0 port 46043 failed: Bad access
* Failed to connect to smtp.gmail.com port 465 after 37 ms: Couldn't connect to server

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection
curl: (7) Failed to connect to smtp.gmail.com port 465 after 37 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

2. when the batch file is run through command prompt, mail is delivered.. What could be the issue?

Comment: The thing I find weird is that you are able to send emails with this method. `Google` stopped allowing password authentications since May 2022.. Here is the page : https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255 - Do you use a particular method in your `gmail` account ?

Comment: See also https://support.google.com/mail/thread/101747111/sending-an-email-using-curl?hl=en

Comment: Google allows it and it worked in my case. I setup mine last month only. I am aware of this Google notification regarding the stopping of less secure apps.

Comment: My issue is when I click on the batch file, curl does not connect as described above. Similar is the case when I used task sch in Windows. However, when I run the script through command line, curl connects and sends the mail successfully and I received the mail without any issues.